# Android: How to periodically check current location without draining the battery

Tags: android, location

I have a background service which works periodically by `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`.
It wakes up every amount of time (let's say 60 seconds for example) and checks for the location.

The location is checked by `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, listener);` and the actual location is collected from the listener's `onLocationChanged`.

Now, when the phone is outside and GPS reception is good, this works fine.
But, if the phone is inside, the GPS is almost always active - looking for a signal, and the battery is drained rapidly.

I created another thread using a Handler and a Runnable in order to conrol the GPS active time accurately:
I used `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);` and `locManager.removeUpdates(listener);` so I can open and close the GPS as I want.
In this case, I can open the GPS for the exact amount of time, but found out that it doesn't lock in an area with good reception even after 10 seconds. So here I'm draining the battery again...

I'm using API level 7, hence I cannot use `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate`.
I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to optimize this process?
2. Will upgrading to API level 9 (and use `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate`) improve the process significantly? I mean, does it worth upgrading?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I can tell you that phone GPS systems sometimes need several minutes, rather than ten seconds to get a fix (probably depending on phone model). Once found, future fixes are much quicker — probably within your 10 second limit. Perhaps spend two or three minutes attempting to get a fix every quarter of an hour? Or maybe there's some way of getting enough detail to tell whether or not there's a good signal more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

How about NETWORK_PROVIDER explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)?
You could have a system that if you cannot find a location in limited set of time, which means you are inside or GPS reception is not good enough, you can use the network location instead. Since that uses less battery, it would at least be a workaround or alternative. But the presicion would be lower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried it and the results are not so good. But in any case, it doesn't solve the original problem: I'd like to be able to work with GPS when there is good reception and to turn it off when there isn't.

Comment: How about you store the new taken location in something? If the value is null, the program will keep trying, and when it is filled, the GPS will disable and show that new taken value. And then from that moment, you can count your 60 seconds until the next check. So in psuedo:

`while true{
   somevariable = null;
   while somevariable == null{
       somevariable = gpslocation;}
   wait 60 seconds;
}`
Or something like this.